# Should we include the industry variables when we control for year*industry fixed effects?

Tags: finance, regression, econometrics, paneldata

In panel data, we control for firms and years fixed effects even we also have some time-variant firm-level regressors.

I am wondering whether it also happens at the industry level. If it is the case, why [Alminas,2019](https://oup.silverchair-cdn.com/oup/backfile/Content_public/Journal/rfs/32/7/10.1093_rfs_hhy094/3/internet_appendix_hhy094.pdf?Expires=1624056896&Signature=Qp6dkkiXdYUG18PGUvYFJWjS5OQ0qlzdpw%7EoLpkonoxZHKxgNtivv1L8gqdAd9N-zsP11sniz6lSwdIevVjNxunBDDWt4MwOiH-WQ8GRLiguSRUmPZzm2-kLJXDJr5c7Er8T9veW%7EQE8ZlCSMp36KgjMuBl%7E%7EaDRYTqIZqB7jqgN%7EzkXzOSMFz3GKC72kuKPHtNVMNPMInazGceWF32OQXingfCfADlzDQ9P%7Eoh6GRtFczvsQk2Sr1Vm5pgxEGiJvRtJn6FeBBL3MmRUzxtv48Fe1N9iDWRUC-cJTFkfoXLNioSqqSqEaKMevuwneRELa1qTjgvmnF0sqR299sGrTg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIE5G5CRDK6RD3PGA) control for the industry fixed effect but excluded the industry control variable on column (4) of Table IA2 as below:
[image]

And I am wondering why we need to control for firm, and *year x industry* effects at the same time? Whether they duplicate each other ? What exactly when they control for all firm, *industry x year* fixed effect?

Update: I found [a discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466607/what-is-the-difference-between-region-year-and-region-year-fixed-effects) partly relating to this but mainly about the mathematical side.